# Read prefixed envs in bash -c

Tags: bash

I need to set HTTP proxy in my install script like this:

```bash
HTTPS_PROXY="http://1.2.3.4:4321" bash -c "$(curl -L https://my.script.com/install.sh)"
```

Here:

- My *install.sh* also need `$HTTPS_PROXY` to download these real binary files, and
- The command line `curl` are also proxyed by `$HTTPS_PROXY`, but it can't read the ENV set before head. I have to write like this:

```bash
HTTPS_PROXY="http://1.2.3.4:4321" bash -c "$(HTTPS_PROXY=http://1.2.3.4:4321 curl -L https://my.script.com/install.sh)"

# or like this

HTTPS_PROXY="http://1.2.3.4:4321" bash -c "$(curl -x http://1.2.3.4:4321 -L https://my.script.com/install.sh)"
```

Is there any way to set ENV(here `$HTTPX_PROXY`) only once for my conditon?

---

My bash verison:

```bash
$ bash  --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

---

It seems that this is ok, I need to test it under different bash:

```bash
HTTPS_PROXY="http://1.2.2.3:4321" bash -c "curl -L https://my.script.com/install.sh | bash"
```

Comment: Why do you need to run `bash -c` ?

Comment: @Paolo For legacy reason, the scripts already there, it works fine except the proxy case.

Comment: See [What's the 'right' format for the HTTP_PROXY environment variable? Caps or no caps?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212894/264812).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the double quotes, the `curl` command runs before the `HTTPS_PROXY` assignment and `bash -c`. I'm guessing you want

```
HTTPS_PROXY="http://1.2.3.4:4321" bash -c 'eval "$(curl -s -L https://my.script.com/install.sh)"'
```

which will set the value of `HTTPS_PROXY` for Bash, which then runs `curl` and evaluates its output as a command to run.

The `eval` and the added double quotes around the command substitution are necessary if the output spans multiple lines (or otherwise needs to be protected from whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion). I also added `-s` to the `curl` options to avoid having it output progress messages.

Comment: use single quote works fine, the ENV passed to command `curl`, but `bash` run failed, says `bash: #: command not found.` It seems that the `curl` return ok, but bash failed to run the *install.sh*.

Comment: It's because the quoting is wrong. I simply assumed you had tested the script in isolation; but see update now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add proxy settings for `user-level` and `system-level`.

- **For System-Level Environment Variables:** `/etc/bashrc`, `/etc/bash_profile`, and `/etc/environment`
- **For User-Level Environment Variables:** `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` (for some systems: `~/.bash_profile`)

**For System Level:** `/etc/environment` (open with any editor: nano, vi, vim, etc.):

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://1.2.3.4:4321"
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://1.2.3.4:4321"
export NO_PROXY="192.168.*.*,10.*.*.*,localhost,127.0.0.1"
```

then, log off, restart, or run directly to enable settings:

```
source /etc/environment
```

**For User Level:** `~/.bashrc` (open with any editor: nano, vi, vim, etc.):

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://1.2.3.4:4321"
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://1.2.3.4:4321"
export NO_PROXY="192.168.*.*,10.*.*.*,localhost,127.0.0.1"
```

then, log off, restart, or run directly to enable settings:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Set the ENV globally may not a acceptable option, this may currupt user-added ENVs. The ENV should only available for current command.

Answer (score 0):

It's more readable if you add another bash call :

```
HTTPS_PROXY="http://1.2.3.4:4321" bash -c 'curl -s -L https://my.script.com/install.sh | bash'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a sub shell, i.e.

```
(export  HTTPS_PROXY="http://1.2.3.4:4321"; bash -c "$(curl -L https://my.script.com/install.sh)")
```